# Why does my program makes my robot turn the power off?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, controls, robotics, pid-controller

I'm trying to put together a programmed robot that can navigate the room by reading instructions off signs (such as bathroom-right). I'm using the AlphaBot2 kit and an RPI 3B+.

the image processing part works well, but for some reason, the MOTION CONTROL doesn't work.
I wrote a simple PID controller that "feeds" the motor, but as soon as motors start turning, the robot turns off.

```
iPWM = 20 # initial motor power in duty cycle
MAX_PWM = 100 
dt = 0.001 # time step

#PID PARAMETERS#
KP = 0.2
KD = 0.01
KI = 0.00005

targets = ['BATHROOM', 'RESTAURANT', 'BALCONY']

class PID(object):
    def __init__(self,target):
        
        self.target = target
        self.kp = KP
        self.ki = KI
        self.kd = KD 
        self.setpoint = 320
        self.error = 0
        self.integral_error = 0
        self.error_last = 0
        self.derivative_error = 0
        self.output = 0
        
    def compute(self, pos):
        self.error = self.setpoint - pos
        #self.integral_error += self.error * TIME_STEP
        self.derivative_error = (self.error - self.error_last) / dt
        self.error_last = self.error
        self.output = self.kp*self.error + self.ki*self.integral_error + self.kd*self.derivative_error
        if(abs(self.output)>= MAX_PWM-iPWM and (((self.error>=0) and (self.integral_error>=0))or((self.error<0) and (self.integral_error<0)))):
            #no integration
            self.integral_error = self.integral_error
        else:
            #rectangular integration
            self.integral_error += self.error * dt
        
        if self.output>= MAX_PWM-iPWM:
            self.output = MAX_PWM-iPWM
    
            
        elif self.output <= -MAX_PWM:
            self.output = iPWM - MAX_PWM
        return self.output
        



class MOTORS(object):
    
    def __init__(self,ain1=12,ain2=13,ena=6,bin1=20,bin2=21,enb=26):
        self.AIN1 = ain1
        self.AIN2 = ain2
        self.BIN1 = bin1
        self.BIN2 = bin2
        self.ENA = ena
        self.ENB = enb
        self.PA  = iPWM
        self.PB  = iPWM

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setup(self.AIN1,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.AIN2,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.BIN1,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.BIN2,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.ENA,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.ENB,GPIO.OUT)
        self.PWMA = GPIO.PWM(self.ENA,500)
        self.PWMB = GPIO.PWM(self.ENB,500)
        self.PWMA.start(self.PA)
        self.PWMB.start(self.PB)
        self.stop()

    def forward(self):
        self.PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PA)
        self.PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PB)
        GPIO.output(self.AIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.AIN2,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN2,GPIO.HIGH)
    
    def updatePWM(self,value):
        if value<0:
            self.PA = iPWM+abs(value)
            self.PB = iPWM
            self.PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PA)
            self.PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PB)
        if value>0:
            self.PA = iPWM
            self.PB = iPWM+value
            self.PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PB)
            self.PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PA)
        if value ==0:
            self.PA = iPWM
            self.PB = iPWM
            self.PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PB)
            self.PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(self.PA)
            
        GPIO.output(self.AIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.AIN2,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN2,GPIO.HIGH)
        
        
    
    def stop(self):
        self.PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        self.PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        GPIO.output(self.AIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.AIN2,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.BIN2,GPIO.LOW)
```

then I have the loop over the camera captures, where i identify the nearest sign and calculate his width and x coordiante of its center:

```
cx = int(x+w//2)

    if d<= 60:
        mot.stop()
        GPIO.cleanup()
dutyCycle = pid.compute(cx)
pwm = mot.updatePWM(dutyCycle)
```

Comment: Very likely, the program itself is not shutting the robot off. However, there may be too much power draw from your power source, resulting in a voltage dip beyond what the RPI can tolerate, so it shuts itself off to protect itself. Is saw this happen many times when writing robotics code for the RPI. check your power supply channels.

Comment: is it possible that if ill turn off the VNC viewer and won't show any image will sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not the software. Your power supply is not sufficient or stable enough to power your motors and the Raspberry Pi.  It is a very common problem. Either:

- Use separate power supplies which is recommended
- Or Increase your main power supply and use some short of stabilization of power

What power supply and power configuration are you using?

Comment: thanks for your answer,
I'm using 2 14500 3.7 v batteries, as the manufacturer recommends.
also, the robot kit comes with some functions which works great, i honestly dont think its a power supply issue because ive set the motor in a mch lower speed

Comment: Do a test, add a separate power supply for the Raspberry and see if the problem goes away. Just plug it in on the recommended power supply and hold the robot so the wheels can spin without it moving. I am pretty sure the problem will go away.

Comment: @ofersimchovitch did you have any luck with it?

Comment: yes sir! you were right!
now I'm struggling to make the robot stay in his path, for some reason the control doesn't work

Comment: I just posted a new question, will appreciate your input